# how to skip the first row en replace non value with 0

Tags: python

I have a csv file with first row with dates that i don't need,i would like to skip that but it doesn't work. And how do i need to replace my non-value with 0.

```
fp = open( "estat_sdg_07_11.csv") 
data = []
while True:
    buffer = fp.readline().strip() 
    if buffer == "":
        break 
    buffer = str(buffer)
    data.append(buffer)
fp.close()
```

these are the first  lines of my file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Wlx.png)

Comment: Hi @RobbeDegryse can you include at least 1 or 2 lines of your file to give the full context?

Comment: Don't show your data as a picture. We can't run your code against a picture. Pick those lins out of the .csv in a text editor and edit your question to include those lines as code.

Answer (score 1):

First off, try to use `with` statement as much as you can. It handles opening and closing file in an appropriate manner in case an exception occurs.

`open` gives you an Iterator which you can easily skip the first row by doing `next()` on it :

```
with open("estat_sdg_07_11.csv") as f:
    next(f) # skipping the first row.
    for line in f:
        # do what you wanna do
```

btw, if you are working with csv files, `csv` module can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is my csv content:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,,1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d,e,f,,1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d,e,f,,1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d,e,f,,1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d,e,f,,1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d,e,f,,1,2,3,4
```

Try this way. This skips the first line and fills  `data` with striped lines

```
fp = open( "estat_sdg_07_11.csv","r") 
lines = fp.readlines()
data=[ l.strip() for l in lines[1:] ]
fp.close()
```

This  also add zeros if an element of the list is empty

```
fp = open( "estat_sdg_07_11.csv","r") 
lines = fp.readlines()
data = [ [0 if x=="" else x for x in l.strip().split(",")]  for l in lines[1:] ]  
fp.close()
```

or ...

```
fp = open( "f.csv","r")
data = [ [0 if x=="" else x for x in l.strip().split(",")]  for l in fp.readlines()[1:] ]
fp.close()
```

The result should be  a list of  rows  represented by a list of column values.
Something like this:

```
print(data)
```

output:

```
[["a","b","c",1,4,0],
["a","b","c",1,4,0],
["a","b","c",1,4,0]]
```

Comment: `fp.close()` - you need the parentheses.

Comment: It isn't really needed to read all lines, and then make a copy out of that list by slicing...